# Undesired space between Rectangle patches in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code draws two red rectangles.
The red rectangles should be next to each other, with no space between. In the python plot, this is OK. In the exported pdf, there is a thin but noticeable white space between the rectangles. Is there some way of fixing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig1 = plt.figure();
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal');
ax.set_xticks([]);
ax.set_yticks([]);

#add first patch
dx=1.0;
loc=(0.0,0.0);
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),dx,dx,facecolor='red',edgecolor='none',linewidth=0));

#add second patch
dx=1.0;
loc=(1.0,0.0);
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),dx,dx,facecolor='red',edgecolor='none',linewidth=0));

ax.set_xlim([-1,3]);
ax.set_ylim([-1,2]);
fig1.show();
plt.savefig('spaceTest.pdf');
```

All is OK in the python plot:
[image]

But there is white space in the pdf:[image]

Comment: One workaround might be to use the `edgecolor` (i.e. set it to the same color)?

Answer (score 2):

The thin line comes from inexact arithmetic. You calculate the points  of the rectangle with integer arithmetic, but you should force float arithmetic.

For instance: Instead of

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((float(loc[0]-dx/2),float(loc[1]-dx/2)),float(dx),float(dx),facecolor='red',edgecolor='none',linewidth=0));
```

use

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),float(dx),float(dx),facecolor='red',edgecolor='none',linewidth=0));
```

Using `2.0` instead of `2` gives `0.5` instead of `0` as division result.

If this doesn't help, you should also turn [Antialiasing off](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_antialiased):

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),float(dx),float(dx),facecolor='red',edgecolor='none',linewidth=0, antialiased = False));
```

Comment: If I fix this, it still shows the thin line (I edited the question). When I originally noticed this, all those numbers were rationals (fractions.Fraction).

Comment: Another problem could be antialiasing. I've extended my post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `edgecolor="none"`.
Force the `edgecolor` and the `facecolor` to be the same, and don't set `linewidth=0`.

This should produce a line-free PDF:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig1 = plt.figure();
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal');
ax.set_xticks([]);
ax.set_yticks([]);

#add first patch
dx=1.0;
loc=(0.0,0.0);
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),float(dx),float(dx),facecolor='red',edgecolor='red'));  # <---
#add second patch
dx=1.0;
loc=(1.0,0.0);
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((loc[0]-dx/2.0,loc[1]-dx/2.0),float(dx),float(dx),facecolor='red',edgecolor='red'));  # <---
ax.set_xlim([-1,3]);
ax.set_ylim([-1,2]);
fig1.show();
plt.savefig('spaceTest.pdf');
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595779/how-to-remove-gaps-between-adjacent-matplotlib-patches/71798527#71798527) for a solution with a PatchCollection.