# How to remove gaps between adjacent matplotlib patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a collection of finite element data with colored patches used to represent the value in each element.

Unfortunately, when I plot the patches I get small gaps between adjacent patches.

I have created an example script below to describe the problem.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

nodes = [[0.1, 0.1],
        [0.25, 0.1],
        [0.75, 0.9],
        [0.1, 0.9],
        [0.9, 0.1],
        [0.9, 0.9]]
        
elems =[[0,1, 2, 3],
        [1, 4, 5, 2]]

patches = []
for elem in elems:
    xy = np.array([nodes[i] for i in elem])
    elem = mpatches.Polygon(xy, closed=True, snap=False, antialiased=True)
    patches.append(elem)

col = PatchCollection(patches)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.add_collection(col)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot with the unwanted gap. Adjusting the shape of the plotting window changes the appearance of the gap.
[image]

At the moment my workaround is to set col.set_edgecolor("face")` and to include a small edge width. However, it's hard to set the edge to reduce artifacts when there is a range of different patch sizes.

Edit: as @tdy pointed out increasing the `dpi` when saving the figure helps reduce the gap, but doesn't eliminate it entirely. With an excessive `dpi` of 1000 the gap is only visible if you zoom in (click the image first) on a high res monitor.
[image]

For example for my real data with no edge width (`edgecolor`=None) there are lines separating each element.
[image]

Setting `edgecolor="face"` with `linewidth=1.0` removes the lines between elements, but adds small artifacts at the corners of cells. This are particularly visible at the front of the geometry where the colors are very different and the elements are small.
[image]
[image]

Reducing the `linewidth` to `0.5` reduces the impact of these artifacts, but the lines between the larger elements in the middle start to reappear.
[image]
[image]

Is it possible to fix these gaps? I know this is a small thing, but I'd love to have a way to plot my data in python without artifacts.

I have tried setting `snap=False` and `antialisased=True`, but neither had any effect.

Comment: That is the most frustrating thing I have ever seen!  I have gone through most of the possible kwargs for `mpatches.Polygon`, but couldn't find anything.  It's not really a solution to the problem, more of a work-around, but you could change the thousandths of the position so there is a very small overlap: `nodes = [[0.1, 0.1], [0.249, 0.1], [0.749, 0.9], [0.1, 0.9], [0.9, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9], [0.251, 0.1], [0.751, 0.9]]` and `elems =[[0, 6, 7, 3], [1, 4, 5, 2]]`.

Comment: When you say `edgecolor='face'` also produces artifacts in some cases, could you provide sample data for that scenario?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to produce a simple script showing the artifacts that come from adding a small edge width, but I did include some images from my real data with and without an edge width.

Comment: @JoshAnibal, would it be possible for you to share (a subset of) the data you are using to generate these images, so we can help you debug the issue?

Comment: Without having looked into too much detail, this seems related to [matplotlib issue 1188](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188).

Answer (score 2):

While setting the `color` of the whole collection does remove the gap as @rvd suggested, this limits us to 1 color for all polygons:

```
col = PatchCollection(patches, color='C0') # limit 1 color per collection
```

A more robust solution is to set the `color` of each polygon and enable [`match_original`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection) in the collection:

> **`match_original`** : If `True`, use the colors and linewidths of the original patches.

This allows us to have distinct colors per patch instead of 1 global color per collection:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# use numpy arrays to simplify indexing
nodes = np.array([[0.1, 0.1], [0.25, 0.1], [0.75, 0.9], [0.1, 0.9], [0.9, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]])
elems = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5, 2]])
colors = np.array(['C0', 'C4']) # color per elem

# set color per polygon
patches = [mpatches.Polygon(nodes[e], color=c) for e, c in zip(elems, colors)]
#                                     -------

# retain original polygon colors
collection = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
#                                     -------------------

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(collection)

plt.show()
```

Of course if you only want one color, you can remove the `zip` and just set a single color (as long as `match_original` is enabled in the collection):

```
patches = [mpatches.Polygon(nodes[e], color='C0') for e in elems]
collection = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
```

[image]

---

**Update:** As I can't reproduce the artifacts using the sample data, try using these extra options on your end:

- `rasterized=True` and `linewidth=0` in the collection
- `dpi=600` (or higher) when saving the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# use numpy arrays to simplify indexing
nodes = np.array([[0.1, 0.1], [0.25, 0.1], [0.75, 0.9], [0.1, 0.9], [0.9, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]])
elems = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5, 2]])
colors = np.array(['C0', 'C4']) # color per elem

# set color per polygon
patches = [mpatches.Polygon(nodes[e], color=c) for e, c in zip(elems, colors)]
#                                     -------

# retain original polygon colors
collection = PatchCollection(patches, snap=True, match_original=True, rasterized=True, linewidth=0)
#                                                -------------------  ---------------  -----------

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(collection)

fig.savefig('fe.png', dpi=600)
#                     -------
```

Comment: You are absolutely right that setting different colors is a must. Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately as I said in my comment to @rvd, setting `color` adds an edge with color and thus will add other artifacts. I have updated my question to highlight what unwanted artifacts can come from adding a colored edge to fill the gaps.

Comment: @JoshAnibal I see. It's hard to test since I can't reproduce the artifacts, but I added an update (new section at the bottom) with some extra options you can try on your end.

Comment: The updated options (rasterized + high dpi) are probably the best bet for now, based on the github link that Paul Brodersen just posted ([issue #1188](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188)).

Comment: Increasing the dpi with a slight edge width seems to be the best work around.
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by using `PatchCollection` colors and different PatchCollections.

PatchCollection -> no lines, even without `edgecolors` and without `linewidth=0`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

nodes = [[0.1, 0.1],
         [0.25, 0.1],
         [0.75, 0.9],
         [0.1, 0.9],
         [0.9, 0.1],
         [0.9, 0.9]]

elems = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
         [1, 4, 5, 2]]

collections = []
for elem in elems:
    xy = np.array([nodes[i] for i in elem], dtype=float)
    collections.append(PatchCollection([mpatches.Polygon(xy)], snap=True, color='black'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for col in collections:
    ax.add_collection(col)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have no idea why this works.

Edit: Applied [tdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13138364/tdy) suggestions from the comments.

Comment: OP already used this: _"At the moment my workaround is to set `edgecolor="face"` and to include a small edge width. However, It hard to set the edge to reduce artifacts when there is a range of different patch sizes."_

Comment: You're right. However, the crucial command seems to be PatchCollection.set_color.

Comment: Ok, we'll see if that's what OP is looking for. Note that instead of looping `set_color`, you could just set the `color` param in the first place: `collections.append(PatchCollection([mpatches.Polygon(xy, linewidth=0)], color='C0'))`

Comment: That's a good addition. The crucial difference seems to be setting the color of the collection vs setting it for the individual patches.

Comment: Actually there seems to be another artifact in your example. Notice the small ridge in the bottom left (around x=0.25)

Comment: It seems to be due to the different way you add the patch collection. If you just use OP's example and set `col = PatchCollection(patches, color='C0')` it seems to work with no artifacts https://i.stack.imgur.com/nImQ1.png

Comment: Seems to depend many things. I needed to set `snap=True` to get rid of it.

Comment: I believe this works because using the kwarg `color` sets both the edge and face color. 
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.AsteriskPolygonCollection.set_color
You can verify this by passing `edgecolor` and `color` both as kwargs to `PatchCollection`.
It will only use the value of `color` for the edge color.

In practice this is the same as the mentioned work around of adding an edge of the same color. I have edited the question to show what kind of unwanted artifacts this can cause.