# How to fill two polygons uniformely so there is no boundary between them?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, polygon

I have two polygons that make two rectangle next to each other. But the problem is when making the plot there is a boundary, I am trying to generate a structure for the Electromagnetic simulatnion, and the simulation will see that there is a wall. How can I uniformely fill this two polygons?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polygons = [[(5.0, 0.05), (10.0, 0.05), (10.0, -0.05), (5.0, -0.05)],
 [(0.0, 0.05), (5.0, 0.05), (5.0, -0.05), (0.0, -0.05)]]

for item in polygons:
        xs, ys = zip(*item)
        plt.fill(xs,ys)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Having option for fill 'k' that plots black will not work because the boundary will still be there during the simulation. Here is the example:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. How do the two images correspond to each other? Is there some issue in the first image?

Comment: The problem seems related to [this very recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595779/how-to-remove-gaps-between-adjacent-matplotlib-patches), still without answer.

Comment: yeah, it's the same issue, but different approach for creating an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. [Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798527/12149698): Create patches with identical `facecolor` and `edgecolor`
2. [Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798615/12149698): Use a `PatchCollection` and use `PatchCollection.set_colors` to set the facecolor (or directuly use `color=...` when creating the `PatchCollection`)